# R - Changing the Magnitude of the x-axis with ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, axis-labels

I am student self-learning R. I have a simple question in relation to ggplot2.

Currently, I have plotted a graph with the following x-axis.

```
36000 36200 36400 36600 36800
```

I would like to change the magnitude of it to...

```
36.0 36.2 36.4 36.6 36.8
```

without changing the graph.

How would I accomplish this?

Comment: Just a point of clarification - are you trying to change the graph axis labels *without* changing the data in the data frame? (Assuming it's in a data frame - more information and/or sample data would help) Or is changing the underlying data acceptable?

Comment: Yup! My data is in a data frame. The data is basically a `3x3 facet_grid of histograms`. I would like to change the axis labels without changing the data.

Comment: Why don't you just divide the values by 1000?

Comment: That worked!  `ggplot(myData, aes(V1/1000))` :)